# Develop HTML5 Android Apps on Android

Tags: android, html, development-environment

So I finally got my Android tablet in the mail today, and was wondering if there's anyway to develop HTML5 Android apps for Android on an Android.

Comment: What are you seeking besides a browser and a text editor, both of which can be trivially found on the Play Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulation for the tablet.

There is a lot of applications on the google play :

[HTML Builder / Web Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.web2rev.fileshare&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm5ldC53ZWIycmV2LmZpbGVzaGFyZSJd)

[KSWEB: server + PHP + MySQL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb&hl=fr)

But i think that if you are serious about making HTML5 apps, you should buy a computer.

Comment: When I make HTML5 apps for Android on the comp my mom and I share I use PhoneGap and Eclipse IDE for the compiling. I take it there currently isnt an alternative for android users to develop and do it just on an Android. My best solution is to stick with developing html5 web apps?

Comment: @mikethedj4: AIDE allows you to build native Java apps on the device, but your question was for HTML5 apps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'app builder' type app for Android as far as I am aware. However, like others have mentioned, you can certainly download some tools to help your development along. Unfortunately, none of which allow you to compile an app as far as I know. You can easily browse, edit, and upload (FTP) HTML/CSS/JS on your Android with tools like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5lc3Ryb25ncy5hbmRyb2lkLnBvcCJd) and [DroidEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.droidedit&feature=search_result&hl=en) though.

Comment: Following up on this there is an app called AIDE - Android IDE - Java, C++ which allows Android app development on an Android device. Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en